# url redirect exact match including params

Tags: .htaccess

i would like to make a 301 redirect and from an old website using the exact exact url with no extra parameters.

example:

```
/en-direct.php?page=7
```

to go to:

```
http://www.example.org/news/
```

and page:

```
/en-direct.php?page=8
```

to go to:

```
http://www.example.org/awesome-but-totally-different-page/
```

i used:

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/en-direct.php$ http://www.example.org/different-page/
redirectMatch 301 ^/en-direct.php?page=7$ http://www.example.org/news/
redirectMatch 301 ^/en-direct.php?page=8$ http://www.example.org/awesome-but-totally-different-page/
```

however: i get http://www.example.org/different-page/ every time with all the parameters from the redirect page (example - http://www.example.org/different-page?page=7 )

any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to match against the query string, you need to use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=7($|&)
RewriteRule ^en-direct\.php$ http://www.example.org/news/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=8($|&)
RewriteRule ^en-direct\.php$ http://www.example.org/awesome-but-totally-different-page/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^en-direct\.php$ http://www.example.org/different-page/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you. it worked. but how to i add multiple parameters to the RewriteCond? would i do RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=7,another=8($|&) ?

Comment: @AryehArmon it's exactly what the query string will look like, so something like: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=7&another=8$`